# How can I put data from csv file to array using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I want it to be the same file every time rather than having to input a filename or choosing a file when the page opens.  My code below requires me to choose a file, I would like it to just put the data in an array each time the page is refreshed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filename").change(function (e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {

            var csvVal = e.target.result.split("\n"); //lines
            var csvValue = csvVal[0].split(","); //each word
            var word = "";
            var allText = "";

            for (var n = 0; n < csvVal.length - 1; n++) {
                for (var i = -1; i < csvValue.length; i++) {

                    var word = (n + 1) + " " + csvVal[n] + " " + "<br>";
                }
                var allText = allText + word;

                $("#cardData").html(allText);
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
        return false;
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Comment: [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) has some very useful apis for this kind of stuff. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV